# VAT-ID Validation Error "Please enter a valid vat number and select a valid country"

Tags: customer, customer-account, vat, custom-validation, taxvat

for a client we´re using Magento 2.4.5-p1 Open Source.
While creating a new customer account the customers are able to add a VAT-ID to get selected into different customer groups.
For some reason thou all VAT IDs don´t get accepted. It does not matter in which writing style (f.e. DExxxxxx, DE xxxxx, DE xx xxx xxx)

We have already deleted the VAT ID validation button. But we still get the information "Please enter a valid vat number and select a valid country" after a VAT ID was added and the customer wants to save the customer information (my account → new customer). As long as the error is there the saving is not possible. We cannot figure out why the VAT IDs do not get accepted

Do you have any idea why we´re facing this issue?

Thank you